# How to fit a gaussian curve over multiple peaks

Tags: matlab, plot, gaussian

I have a plot that has many gaussian plots in varying intensities. I want to fit a Gaussian plot over all these many plots. Is there a way to make this automatic? If not, how would you suggest that I do it? I thought of just finding the value of each one of the peaks of the plots and fitting a gaussian throught that but I am not sure how accurate that would be.

Comment: Try `gmdistribution`- http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/gmdistribution.html?searchHighlight=gmdistribution. But you have to know the number of the peaks.

Comment: I might not have been clear: I already have a plot:
http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/uploaded_files/18395/2.jpg and  http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/uploaded_files/18396/1.jpg and I want to plot a gaussian over these plots.

Comment: In the second plot (numbered '1') it seems that you have some greate gaussians. So what do you want? the sum of all?

Comment: I want something like that (sorry for bad quality, I drew it in paint) http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=2j0dnqr&s=8#.VB7KhFfitNg 

A Gaussian fit over all these gaussians.. I guess like going throught the peaks of these

Comment: Well then simply take those peaks and fit yourself a gaussian

Comment: Have you tried `cftool` in matlab? You could ajust your settings there (fit function, number of gaussians) in the gui and then export the code to a .m file and have a look how everything works.

Comment: Maybe you can use `normpdf`, with the mean and std of your data as parameters for the function